# JFormattedTextField get value without mask

Tags: java, swing, mask, jformattedtextfield

I've set a mask to a `JFormattedTextField` in java
like this:

```
MaskFormatter mf1 = new MaskFormatter("#.## mmol/g");
mf1.setValueContainsLiteralCharacters(false);
mf1.setPlaceholderCharacter('_');
JFormattedTextField field = new JFormattedTextField(mf1);
```

Once the field is shown in the frame, after I write something in it and click "send",
I'm using `getValue()` to get the text on the field
but it's returning **empty**.

If I use `getText()` to get the text, I got

```
0.12 mmol/g
```

but I want only the 012 to insert this to my db... without the mmol/g and the dot

What do I need to do to get the value without the mask...
**(it's not the only mask. I have a lot of masks so I dont need to regex or something like this...)**

Part of my full code.
This the function that create the mask field:

```
 public void createTextField(String label, int xPos, int yPos, JPanel fieldset,
    String val, int fontSize, String format, String fieldName, String fieldType) {
JFormattedTextField field = null;
MaskFormatter mf1 = null;
try {
    JLabel fieldLabel = new JLabel(label);
    fieldLabel.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, fontSize));
    fieldLabel.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    fieldLabel.setBounds(xPos, yPos, xPercent(fieldset.getWidth(), 46), fieldsHeight);

    fieldset.add(fieldLabel);

    switch(format) {
    case "percent":
        mf1 = new MaskFormatter("##%");
        //mf1.setPlaceholderCharacter('');
        break;
    case "c":
        mf1 = new MaskFormatter("## C°");
        break;
    case "double":
        mf1 = new MaskFormatter("#.##");
        break;
    case "double1":
        mf1 = new MaskFormatter("#.###");
        break;
    case "mpa":
        mf1 = new MaskFormatter("## MPa");
        break;
    case "mpas":
        mf1 = new MaskFormatter("## mPa.s");
        break;
    case "ppm":
        mf1 = new MaskFormatter("### ppm");
        break;
    case "mg":
        mf1 = new MaskFormatter("#.# mg KOh/g");
        break;
    case "gmol":
        mf1 = new MaskFormatter("### g/mol");
        break;
    case "mmol":
        mf1 = new MaskFormatter("#.## mmol/g");
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    if(mf1 != null) {
        mf1.setValueContainsLiteralCharacters(false);
        mf1.setPlaceholderCharacter('_');
    }

    field = new JFormattedTextField(mf1);
    field.setBounds(fieldLabel.getWidth() + 5 + xPos, yPos, xPercent(fieldset.getWidth(), 46), fieldsHeight);
    field.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, new Color(174,174,174)));
    field.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, fontSize));
    field.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
    field.setText(val);

    if(format == "int") { // only numbers in the field
        field.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                char caracter = e.getKeyChar();
                if (((caracter < '0') || (caracter > '9'))
                        && (caracter != '\b')) {
                    e.consume();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    fieldset.add(field);

} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

formFields.put(fieldName, new formField(fieldName, field, null, null, null, mf1, fieldType));
```

}

And this is the part that is executed after I click some button where I'm using getValue. After this part the output of variable "text" is empty

```
        formField field = pair.getValue();

        String text = null;
        if(field.textField != null)
            text = (String) field.textField.getValue();
        if(field.textArea != null)
            text = field.textArea.getText();
        if(field.select != null)
            text = "" + ((comboItem) field.select.getSelectedItem()).getId();
        if(field.radios != null)
            text = getSelectedButtonText(field.radios);
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I would think that `getValue()` would work. If you don't get help soon, consider creating and posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) where you condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles and runs, has no outside dependencies (such as need to link to a database or images), has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels like i said, i used getValue() and its return empty string...

Comment: I know -- I did read your post. Again it should be working, and if it's not something's wrong. Again, please consider posting a [mcve] so we can test and modify your code and see the problem for ourselves. Again, we don't want to see your entire program, but rather a minimal program that runs and that shows us your problem. Note the program should be small enough to post here, and not in a link. Good luck.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels ok i edited the post

Comment: Thanks, but please re-read the [mcve] link. The key part missing from your posted code is still that we cannot copy it, paste it into our ide's and run it unchanged. You're still posting program fragments and not a small self-contained compilable and runnable program. Again if you follow the protocol, you'll likely get better answers quicker.

Comment: The problem solved by getValue (its working only mask field, i tested unmask field)

Comment: Good for you. I knew that `getValue()` ***should*** work.